# Implement Robert's edge operator for edge detection in python opencv

Tags: python, opencv

i have to implement Robert's operator for edge detection. I'm using Python + OpenCV.

This is the code I have come up with, I'm not sure if this is correct.

```py
img = cv2.imread('image_path/image.jpg', 0)

kernelx = np.array([[1, 0], [0, -1]])
kernely = np.array([[0, 1], [-1, 0]])

img_robertx = cv2.filter2D(img, -1, kernelx)
img_roberty = cv2.filter2D(img, -1, kernely)
prewitt = cv2.add(img_robertx, img_roberty)

cv2.imshow(prewitt)
```

As suggested by [DrYuanShenghai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11530294/dr-yuan-shenghai):

```py
kernelx = np.array([[1, 0], [0, -1]])
kernely = np.array([[0, 1], [-1, 0]])
img_robertx = cv2.filter2D(blured_img, -1, kernelx)
img_roberty = cv2.filter2D(blured_img, -1, kernely)
grad = cv2.addWeighted(img_robertx, 0.5, img_roberty, 0.5, 0)
```

Comment: grad = cv.addWeighted(img_robertx, 0.5, img_roberty, 0.5, 0)   also make sure that the img_robertx/y are bounded within 0 to 255.